# Eslint or prettier is adding 2 semi colons to the end of a line in vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

In VScode when I accidentally leave off a semi colon at the end of a javascript line and save the file, vscode (prettier or eslint or both) fixes this by adding 2 semi colons to the end of the line. Example

Original line

```
const x = 1
```

Fixed line

```
const x = 1;;
```

I want it to add only 1 ;

Where would I look to fix this? *facepalm*

Comment: Did you manage to find what was causing this? I am hitting the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR: Check your ESLint rules, make sure you don't have a redundant one that is already being taken care of by your plugins.**

I was having this issue. I solved it in my `.eslintrc.json` file, which I had mis-configured.

I have both the plugin installed for prettier

```
    "plugins": ["babel", "react", "prettier"],
```

as well a rule set for eslint to add semi colons

```
    "rules": {
        "semi": ["error", "always"],
```

When I take either that rule out or the prettier plugin out, it would go to only adding one semicolon.

However, when I would take out the prettier plugin, it would also give the error:
`Definition for rule 'prettier/prettier' was not foundeslint(prettier/prettier)`

So the rule setting seemed to be redundant with the plugin, and removing the rule fixed this issue.